# Cloning an Amazon Linux Instance

Tags: backup, amazon-ec2, clone, instance

I currently have an amazon instance (Medium - High CPU) running off the instance store with most of my data and code sitting in /mnt mounted to sda2. The instance is just the way i need it to work. How can I clone this instance and make an exact copy (data and all) to another (preferably cheaper, micro) instance for testing my new code changes? Also what backup suggestions are recommend for this setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with instance store, your instance if terminated will restore your data. I suggest you put the important data to an EBS volumes.

Please see my post http://www.capsunlock.net/2009/12/create-ebs-boot-ami.html 
It's possible to clone the current instance and make  an EBS backed AMI.